# Only the first IF(AND) statement works but not the rest

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have 3 cells which consists of `Chief, Senior and Intermediate` and from those 3 only one of them can have a value at any time.

Example: if Chief has a value of 40, both Senior and Intermediate will be empty cells.

All these three cells link up with a `Scribe` cell where an IF(AND) statement is set up. The statement has **2 conditions** to needs to be met that contains AD5="Y" and that one of the three cells has a value in them. In which the scribe formula below depicts as such:

```
=IF(AND(AD5="Y",W7),W7,IF(AND(AD5="Y",X7),X7,IF(AND(AD5="Y",Y7),Y7,"")))
```

[image]
[image]

The issue that I am having is that when Chief is 40 and AD5 = "Y" the Scribe outputs 40 (that's good) but when Senior or Intermediate is 40 the scribe cell is empty so I am not sure that is wrong with the formula here.

Comment: Are the entries always numbers and always only one cell can be filled at once?

Comment: Assuming one and only one cell can be filled with a number, try: `=IF(AD5="Y",SUM(W7:Y7),"")`

Comment: Yes always numbers and only cell at any time has numbers

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad get out of my head.  That was what I was getting to.

Comment: Lol that works too, but is there a way for this to work on IF statements ?

Comment: @Scott Craner - finally! a little bit of your genius is rubbing off on me -- now to see if it will stick...

Comment: The problem is that you assume that the `W7` in  `AND(AD5="Y",W7)` returns true when there is a value.  It does not.  Anything that is not 0 will return TRUE.  You need to create the boolean: `AND(AD5="Y",W7<>"")` and do the same with the other three.